# How do I kill a running process in Emacs

Tags: c++, emacs, process

When I compile the c++ file, emacs displays：

> a compilation process is running;kill it?(y or n).

But `y` has no effect. How do I kill an active process in Emacs? there are many running processes in *process list*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if there is a simpler, interactive solution - but using a bit of elisp, you can get a buffer of information of processes by:

`(list-processes)`

If you want a general purpose kill-all running processes, a simple example would be:

`(mapcar 'delete-process (process-list))`

(note that we used of `process-list` here).

If you want to delete a specific process by the name shown in the list processes buffer:

`(delete-process (get-process "name of proc"))`

And here is a simple way you might make this interactive:
(if you do not use IDO, replace `ido-completing-read` with `completing-read` or similar)

```
(defun delete-process-interactive ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((pname (ido-completing-read "Process Name: " 
                    (mapcar 'process-name (process-list)))))

    (delete-process (get-process pname))))
```

And then run or key bind `delete-process-interactive` to tidy up your stray processes.

Though this is a solution, you might want to investigate what is causing this behavior further.  For assistance with that from others, you will need to provide more information.